# "ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches" errors in Unit Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, teamcity, rake-test

I'm running the unit integration tests on my Continous Integration server. I'm getting errors for 3 of them with the same format, here an example for the test "PaymentMethodsControllerTest.test_should_update_active_field":

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:id=>"380742408", :active=>false, :controller=>"payment_methods", :action=>"update_active"}

Stack trace:
test/functional/payment_methods_controller_test.rb:61:in `block in <class:PaymentMethodsControllerTest>'
```

These are the other ones:
 ProductsControllerTest.test_should_update_active_field:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:id=>"9854742", :active=>false, :controller=>"products", :action=>"update_status"}

Stack trace:
test/functional/products_controller_test.rb:61:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

SectionsControllerTest.test_should_update_active_field:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:id=>"260276858", :active=>false, :controller=>"sections", :action=>"update_status"}

Stack trace:
test/functional/sections_controller_test.rb:54:in `block in <class:SectionsControllerTest>'
```

Developers claim that their tests runs ok in their environments, but not me. I'm using ruby 1.9.2p320, Rails 3.2.0

Comment: Are you & your developers using the same gems? i.e. are they also using Rails 3.2 ?

Comment: They are using the same gems and same version of rails. Whatever they already fixed those tests.